# Why do rich and poor countries trade in different goods and why do rich countries trade in similar goods with other rich countries?

Tags: international-trade

I think that differences in climate is one key factor but I think it could be explained by David Ricardo's theory on international trade differences???

Answer (score 2):

The key is production capabilities, not relative specialization. In words of [Hausmann and Rodrik (2006)](http://www.hks.harvard.edu/fs/drodrik/Research%20papers/doomed.pdf):

> The idea that rich (poor) countries tend to export goods exported by other rich
>   (poor) countries is quite obvious and is compatible with many possible theories. For
>   example, in conventional trade theory a la Heckscher-Ohlin, countries export products
>   that are more intensive in the factors of production that are relatively abundant at home.
>   As development takes place, physical, human and institutional capital is accumulated and
>   the products countries export become more intensive in these factors. ...
>
> Labor-abundant countries trade with land- or capital-abundant countries in order to
>   acquire more efficiently the goods that are intensive in the factors they don’t have. The
>   transition between goods is of little significance: they are the passive consequence of
>   changing factor endowments.